# SImple macro needed in Notepad++. Insert character through 400 lines

Tags: macros, notepad++

I need to simple insert an equal symbol (=) onto every line of text I have copied from a spreadsheet. For example, I have copied 2 singular columns looking like:

```
Column A       Column B
Manchester     192.168.1.10
London         192.168.1.11
New York       192.168.1.12
```

I have copied these 2 columns into Notepad++ and now I have:

```
Manchester 192.168.1.10
London 192.168.1.11
New York 192.168.1.12
```

Which is fine... however I now to need make each line have '=' in, between location name and IP address, for example:

```
Manchester = 192.168.1.10
London = 192.168.1.11
New York = 192.168.1.12
```

Does anyone have any ideas how to do this? I know how to get the equal symbol to record in the macro, but can't get the macro to do this for every line!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If every IP address begins with 192. you can simply CTRL+H and replace all occurances of ' 192.' with ' = 192.'

Answer (score 0):

Just use search and replace. Replace " 1" with " = 1".

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> & on the *Replace* tab

Search for `([a-z])(\s+)([1-9])`
Replace with `\1 = \3`

Tick *Regular Expression* & replace.